# Tomcat SSL configuration not working

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have received a certificate and private key from my company, and I created a keystore by the following commanfs:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in myCert.pem -inkey myKey.key -certfile myCert.pem -out mykeystore.p12


keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore mykeystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore mykeystore.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

Then I edited my tomcat `server.xml` `connector` tag as the following:

```
<Connector server="HTTPS"
           address="10.233.29.135"
           port="11033"
           protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           SSLEnabled ="true" 
           sslProtocol ="TLS"
           acceptCount="2000" 
           maxThreads="150"
           minSpareThreads="10" 
           maxPostSize="10240" 
           maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           scheme="https" 
           secure="true" 
           clientAuth="false" 
           enableLookups="false"
           keystoreFile="conf/mykeystore.jks" 
           keystorePass="myPass"
           ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"
           sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1"
           allowTrace="false" 
           xpoweredBy="false"     
           URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

Now the problem is that I am getting the following error when I open website in firefox:

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to 10.233.29.135:11032. 
SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
```

Can someone help me find the problem.

***Note: I am using local server and using the IP address to access the website but the certificate is generated for *.someDomain.com, so I want to know that should I get the error I got or it is related to some other mistake I made.**

Comment: Can you try using `protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"` instead of `protocol="HTTP/1.1"` as described in https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Configuration

Comment: I changed it, restart the server, but still the same error.

Comment: You have your `Connector` listening on `port="11033"` but your error references port 11032 (`10.233.29.135:11032`). Can you try using the correct port?